# What would be the idiomatic way to map this data?

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala and while working I found the need to map some data found within a log file. The log file follows this format (values changed from original):

```
1343,37284.ab1-tbd,283
1344,37284.ab1-tbd,284
1345,37284.ab1-tbd,0
1346,28374.ab1-tbd,107
1347,28374.ab1-tbd,0
...
```

The first number is not important, but the number portion of the second field and the third field are what need to be mapped. I need the map to have keys that correspond to the number portion of the second field that map to a list of every 3rd field that follows it. That was a bad explanation, so as an example here is what I would need after parsing the above log:

```
{
    37284 => { 283, 284, 0 }
    28374 => { 107, 0 }
}
```

The solution I came up with is this:

```
val data = for (line <- Source fromFile "path/to/log" getLines) yield line.split(',')
val ls = data.toList

val keys = ls.map(_(1).split('.')(0).toInt)
val vals = ls.map(_(2).toInt)

val keys2vals = for {
    (k, v) <- (keys zip vals).groupBy(_._1)
    list = v.map(_._2)
} yield (k, list)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Scala? This seems kinda awkward and convoluted to me. (When explaining, please assume little to no background knowledge of langauge features, etc.) Also, if later down the line I wanted to exclude the number zero from the mappings, how would I do so?

**EDIT:**

In addition, how would I similarly turn the data into the form:

```
{
    { 37284, { 283 ,284, 0 } }
    { 28374, { 107, 0 } }
}
```

i.e. a List[(Int, List[Int])]? (This form is for use with apache-spark's indexed rdds)

Comment: Do you actually want a JSON output?  Because that is not valid JSON

Comment: @Tyler - No, that's just the way I used to visualize what I actually wanted. The first one is a Map[Int, List[Int]] and the second is a List[Tuple2[Int, List[Int]]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
val assocList = for {
  line <- Source.fromFile("path/to/log").getLines
  Array(_, snd, thd) = line.split(',')
} yield (snd.split('.')(0).toInt, thd.toInt)
assocList.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

If you want a `List[(Int, List[Int])]`, add `.toList`.

Comment: Yes, that type is what I wanted for the data. Sorry, my description was rather bad.

Comment: This solution is also what I was looking for. I just needed to switch Array(_, snd, thd) with arry since that kind of construct doesn't appear to work, and the references to snd and thd in the yield statement to arry(1) and arry(2), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to write it in fewer lines (arguably clearer too) like this:

```
val l = List((1343,"37284.ab1-tbd",283),
  (1344,"37284.ab1-tbd",284),
  (1345,"37284.ab1-tbd",0),
  (1346,"28374.ab1-tbd",107),
  (1347,"28374.ab1-tbd",0))

// drop the unused data
val m = l.map(a => a._2.split('.')(0).toInt -> a._3)

// transform to Map of key -> matchedValues
m.groupBy(_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2))
```

gives:

```
m: List[(Int, Int)] = List((37284,283), (37284,284), (37284,0), (28374,107), (28374,0))

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(37284 -> List(283, 284, 0), 28374 -> List(107, 0))
```

"Also, if later down the line I wanted to exclude the number zero from the mappings, how would I do so?" - You could `filter` the initial list:

```
val m = l.filter(_._3 != 0).map(a => a._2.split('.')(0) -> a._3)
```

To convert to List[(Int, List[Int])] you just need to call .toList on the resulting Map.

Comment: This doesn't work for my case because the incoming data is of type Iterator[String], or type List[String] if I call toString on the iterator, not List[(Int, String, Int)].

Comment: I noticed that a toInt was needed to convert to List[(Int, List[Int])] - will update

Answer (score 0):

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("path/to/log").getLines.toList
lines.map{x=>
  val Array(_,second,_,fourth) = x.split("[,.]")
  (second,fourth)
}.groupBy(_._1)
.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.